# MERN format date to month, day, year with data from nodejs server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, date

I have a nodejs server that is fetching some data from MongoDb for a react app. When I fetch this data my 'created' value is stored as 2022-02-08T03:27:17.318Z. My question is, How and where do I reformat this to the Month, day, year. Im pretty sure I need to keep my date as this format when storing in db, but I want my user to see 02/08/2022.

here is my Node.js function for listFiles, this has the created value that needs to be changed

```
const listFiles = async (req, res) => {
                try {
                    let files = await Files.find({_user: req.user.id}).select('file_name contacts duplicates failed created')
                    
                    //console.log(created) ----> 2022-02-08T03:27:17.318Z 
                    //I want 02/08/2022 do I do this in this function? or do I do this in React?

                   res.json(files)
                } catch (err) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        error: dbErrorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    })
                }
            }
```

Here is the React Action creator

```
 export const listFiles = () => {
                return async function(dispatch) {
               await 
               axios({
                url:"http://localhost:5000/files/create",
                method:"GET", 
                withCredentials: true
                }).then( res => dispatch({type: LIST_FILES, payload: res.data}))
                }
        }
```

Here is the reducer in frontend React app

```
import { LIST_FILES } from '../actions/types';


export default function (state = [], action) {
    switch (action.type) { 
        case LIST_FILES:
            return action.payload  
            default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution was install a library called react-moment. so npm install react-moment in frontend, and once I fetch data to frontend I can use something like this

```
import React from 'react'
import Moment from 'react-moment'

const Component = () => {


const createdFormatter = (rowData) => {
    const {created} = rowData.row.original // getting data from react-table
    
  return (
      <Media tag={Flex} align="center">
        <Media body className="ml-2">
// add this <Moment /> component and it formats date for me in React.
          <h5 className="mb-0 fs--1 mt-2"><Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY" 
 date={created}/></h5>
        </Media>
      </Media>
  )};

};
```